# Installing Penguin subtitle player on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt

I'm trying Ubuntu 17.10 on a VM. I wanted to install penguin subtitle player (which I already have on my Ubuntu 16.04 host) on the VM. I followed the steps explained on the [repo page on github.](https://github.com/carsonip/Penguin-Subtitle-Player)

First I added the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

then I ran

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install penguin-subtitle-player
```

but I got the error

```
E: Unable to locate package penguin-subtitle-player
```

Comment: 17.10 has not been released yet, and there are no packages for it in the PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the package is not available for ubuntu 17.10 just yet.
but is available for ubuntu 17.04 and 16.04. you should wait for the release or contact them for adding support in 17.10 or just try building it from [source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/penguinsubtitleplayer/files/Penguin%20Subtitle%20Player/).